# on edit mode want to show listbox items as selected

Tags: c#

i am new to silverlight and mvvm.
i am working on a project.In which i am having my table in sql database.
on my main page am showing my whole data in datagrid. and below data grid am having 3 buttons naming as ADD,EDIT,Delete.
now the problem am getting is whenever i click on edit button the child window gets open.
and on child window am having listbox with a multiple select property set on xml,name role type.
now need when evr i select a record on datagrid and then click on edit button.i need listbox shows all those items selected which i selected when i added the record.

pls help me as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to bind the childwindow to the same viewmodel as the datagrid.

Use the datagrid selectedItem Property and bind it to the model of a datarow.
Bind the same selected item to the ListBox in your childwindow.

Assuming you know how to bind to the datagrid / MainPage =>

MainPage:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Source}" SelectedItem={Binding SelectedItem, mode="TwoWay" />
```

ViewModel:

```
public List<YourModel> Source { get; set; }
public YourModel SelectedItem { get; set; }
```

ChildWindow:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource={Binding Source}" SelectedItem={Binding SelectedItem, mode="TwoWay"
```

Let me know if this solves your problem.
If not, explain what I'm missing so I can look in to it.